# gradle war empty jar is added

Tags: gradle, dependencies, runtime, war

war project MyWebApp:

```
 src/main/webapp
```

thare is no java source. jars will be added to war using runtime dependencies.

```
apply plugin: 'war'
dependencies {
     runtime project(':foo')
}
```

an empty jar MyWebApp.jar will be added to war if there is runtime dependencies declared. How to prevent the empty jar from being generated.

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the JAR task, then no JAR is generated.

```
jar.enabled false
```

If there is already a JAR generated and you are not doing a clean build, then delete the generated JAR, or you might wonder that it is still in the WAR.

Comment: Sorry my overlook. the empty jar is from a subproject that is in the process of gradle-ing. actually war plugin has disabled the jar task.

Comment: Well, then disable the jar task of the subproject.